# Зачем нужно задание capacity при инициализации queue?

Tags: java, коллекции, очередь

```
PriorityQueue<String> queue2 = new PriorityQueue<String>(4, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Я одного не могу понять, зачем написано 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите [документацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

`4` - это исходная вместимость (capacity). Это надо для случаев, когда вы примерно знаете, какое количество элементов у вас будет в очереди. Вы можете задать нужный capacity, чтоб под неё выделилась память. Это позволит в будущем избежать лишних аллокаций.

В сорсах это выглядит примерно так - основываясь на `capacity` выделяется память под нужное количество элементов сразу:

```
public PriorityQueue(int initialCapacity,
                         Comparator<? super E> comparator) {
        // Note: This restriction of at least one is not actually needed,
        // but continues for 1.5 compatibility
        if (initialCapacity < 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        this.queue = new Object[initialCapacity];
        this.comparator = comparator;
}
```